# send data displayed in today notification(Today extension) to appdelegate method

Tags: ios, today-extension

I am using today extension

I have displayed the list of events in tableview today notification.

while click on selected row event i want to send in appdelegate method

when click select row I am navigating in my app and call method openurl
but i cann't get selected event in this method or selected row number.

so can we get data from today extension to our app

my current code in todayviewcotroller is

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
     [self.extensionContext openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"TestIt://"]
             completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
     }];
}
```

when click on event send row number to appdelegate method(openurl).

appriciate for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults to store the data between the app and the extensions. But firstly you need to enable app groups.

> To enable data sharing, use Xcode or the Developer portal to enable app groups for the containing app and its contained app extensions. Next, register the app group in the portal and specify the app group to use in the containing app. To learn about working with app groups, see Adding an App to an App Group in Entitlement Key Reference.

After you enable app groups, an app extension and its containing app can both use the NSUserDefaults API to share access to user preferences. To enable this sharing, use the initWithSuiteName: method to instantiate a new NSUserDefaults object, passing in the identifier of the shared group. For example, a Share extension might update the user’s most recently used sharing account, using code like this:

// Create and share access to an NSUserDefaults object.

```
NSUserDefaults *mySharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"com.example.domain.MyShareExtension"];
```

// Use the shared user defaults object to update the user's account.

```
[mySharedDefaults setObject:theAccountName forKey:@"lastAccountName"];
```

Here's the reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1

Edit: How to register yourself to a userdefaults notification

```
 NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:)  
               name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
             object:nil];
```

Comment: I have enabled app group from my app and extension also use nsuserdefault with initwithsuitname method and tried to run app run normally but when click event in notification doesn't call method in todayviewcontroller whenever i remove that nsuserdefault code method called I don't know why?   @Ashraf Tawfeeq

Comment: Add yourself an observer in the UserdefaultsDidChange notification

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a URL, as long as you make sure to include the important data in the URL. For example, you could change your code to look like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TestIt://%d", indexPath.row];
[self.extensionContext openURL:url] completionHandler:nil];
```

Now the URL includes the index of the row that the user tapped on.

Then make sure that your app responds to that URL (which you do in the target settings) and you will receive that URL in your app delegate. You would do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    NSString *tableIndexRow = [url resourceSpecifier];

    // tableIndexRow is a string that contains the tapped row number

    // Do something to handle the tap

    return YES;
}
```

This way your app will know which row the user tapped on, and it can respond in whatever way makes sense for your app. There's a [project on Github](https://github.com/atomicbird/iOS-Extension-Demo) that demonstrates this.

If you need to pass different data, include whatever you need in the URL, and modify your app delegate to handle that data.